# get a variable from a textarea in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

here is what i'm doing but it doesn't work. I have to change the texte in the textarea but I don't know how to get it? thanks

```
<%
  /** Variables */
  String valeurTexte;



 /** Logique */

valeurTexte = request.getParameter("texte");

  valeurTexte=valeurTexte.replaceAll("Ç","&Ccedil;");

 out.println("Votre texte: "+ valeurTexte);

 %>

  <form>   
  <textarea name="texte">ici</textarea>
 <input type='submit'>
</form>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not java should be done only in javascript using getElementById ...

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper please use only english on this website.

Comment: @wrongAnswer I understand, but the OP seems to have trouble explaining his issue in english

Comment: Is this forwarded from a Servlet?

Comment: Je veux aller chercher le texte dans textarea, pour qu'il devient la variable de mon programme java.

Comment: ah, ouais, d'accord, alors, qui est le nom de textarea?

Comment: texte est le nom de textarea

Comment: avez vous tente le methode getText()? c'est essentiel pour la classe textArea

Comment: ty @sharpedge I was about to make that change myself

Comment: il est marqué : The method getText(String) is undefined for the type 
 HttpServletRequest

Comment: ahaha, de ma faute, j'ai lu la reponse de david99world, peut etre ca? il semble que ca marche

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to see exactly what you want from the question, but assuming this is javascript because of the tag, give the textarea an id and do `document.getElementById("myId").innerText=sometext`

or `document.getElementsByName("texte")` and find the textarea

Comment: So I should do my request like this ? valeurTexte = request.document.getElementsByName("texte")

Comment: It is tell me : The method getElementsByName(String) is undefined for the type 
 HttpServletRequest

Comment: Well it depends what you mean by request, if you were hitting a Java controller, you'd probably do a GET to an url endpoint but the above would only amend the DOM.

Comment: How can I change it? so it's work :s